# Lucene lemmatization

Tags: lucene, nlp

I'm indexing some English texts in a Java application with Lucene, and I need to lemmatization them with Lucene 4_1_0. I've found stemming (PorterStemFilter and SnowballFilter), but it not enough.

After lemmatizations I wanted to use a thesaurus for query expansion, does Lucene also include a thesaurus?

If it is not possible I will use the StanfordCoreNLP and WordNet instead.

Do you think that lemmatization may influence the search using Lucene library?

Thanks

Comment: lemmatizations should be  expected to improve accuracy without the loss of information associated with stemming (which can conflate different morphological forms together). Using a second step to expand a lemma using Wordnet should be expected to reduce accuracy and increase recall. The problem of accuracy can be alleviated if you can do a word-sense disambiguation before naively inflating synonyms from word-net (using word2vec) or another semantic similarity algorithm

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you will need to build synonymization support in yourself.